# Is there a Spanish term for a 'mandated reporter'?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, interpretación

I am trying to describe a situation to my Spanish-speaking mother about how a friend of mine, who works with foster children, is required to report anything that was witnessed as abuse or neglect to a supervisor or the police, depending on whether the person was a child or adult.

Comment: So you are looking for a word that describes "a person that reports abuse (or whatever) but only because it is mandatory"?

Comment: Well, I tried to look for a Spanish translation of the term 'mandated reporter' because I got a court case in English, and I'm trying to translate parts of it to Spanish. It's not mandatory.

Comment: Well, by "mandatory" I meant the fact that the person reports abuse because it is mandatory. I did not mean that it were mandatory for you to translate it. I've fixed the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, all foster parents, teachers, counsellors and psychologists, pastors, and anyone who works with vulnerable children and adults, are required by law to report anything that is considered abuse or neglect. That's what I mean by mandatory.

Comment: I live in the United States, but my parents are in Mexico, so I don't know if they have a term like that in North America.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Spanish term used within the US is ***denunciante obligatorio***. See for instance these links:

- [California mandated reporter training child abuse](http://mandatedreporterca.com/training/spgeneraltraining.htm): "Bienvenidos al Entrenamiento de **Denunciante Obligatorio** de Abuso de Menores – California."
- [Denuncias obligatorias - NYS Justice Center](https://www.justicecenter.ny.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Reporting%20Requirements%20for%20Custodians_V2.pdf): "Además, la Ley de Protección de Personas con Necesidades Especiales identifica a determinadas personas que se definen como **denunciantes obligatorios**, y les exige a estas personas que denuncien los incidentes que afecten a personas vulnerables ante el Registro Central de Personas Vulnerables (Vulnerable Persons Central Register, VPCR) del Centro de Justicia."
- [thread Alaska](http://threadalaska.org/index.cfm?fuseaction=calendar.catalog_class&classid=856&typeid=17): "Los proveedores de cuidado de niños están obligados a reportar de abuso y negligencia infantil en el estado de Alaska. Esta formación le ayudará a entender sus responsabilidades como **denunciante obligatorio** [...]"

You can also take a look at these bilingual [Child Abuse Reporting](https://www.sccoe.org/depts/esb/parent/Conference%20Series%20and%20Workshops%2020122013/Child%20Abuse%20Reporting%20SPAN%20ENG%20January%202012.pdf) slides.

Answer (score 3):

Google Translate's choice for *mandated reporter* is *reportero obligatorio*, which sounds terrible for me. Maybe *informante obligatorio* could sound better but I personally recommend to use the following:

> Mi posición/trabajo/situación [como padre de acogida/persona que trabaja con niños de acogida/profesor/psicólogo/whatever] **me obliga a informar** de los abusos y neglicencias [a la autoridad competente].

Sometimes you just can't find a proper noun in Spanish that translates a term in English, but you can always describe the situation and translate that description.

Another option could be just:

> **Estoy obligado a informar** de los abusos.

Or:

> Tengo la **obligación de dar parte** de los abusos a la autoridad.